Restsharp TLS 1.2 or 1.3 configured but callback says it is still Version 1.1
I use an Restsharp RestClient (Edit. .net Framework 4.8) and set the TLS protocol before I do the first web service call via
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

The server supports TLS until 1.3.
I use this to get information about the certification validation
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = calBackCert;

which tries to get the TLS Version used:
    private static bool calBackCert(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        bool success = true;
        if (certificate != null)
        {
             //Get Cert Infos and set success
        }
     
        if (sender is SslStream sslStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" TLS Version: {sslStream.SslProtocol}");
        }

        if (sender is HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"TLS Version: {request.ServicePoint.ProtocolVersion}");
        }

        return success;
    }

The request is a HttpWebRequest and always gives me Version 1.1 as the protocol version.
Why? It should not be allowed to do 1.1 because I set the explicit version before.
Thanks for having a look at my problem.
Cheers
Edit: the server supports TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. The Application is running on a Windows 11 machine that supports all TLS versions
The request.ServicePoint.ProtocolVersion is the wrong place to look for the code but how can you check which TLS version was used? (sender is always HttpWebRequest request)

Remove ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; completely and let the runtime use the best available option. That line prevents the use of TLS 1.3 to begin with. You can't use TLS 1.3 if the OS doesn't support it either. All supported versions of both .NET Framework and .NET Core will use the best option provided by the OS and the remote server. If the remote server doesn't support TLS 1.2 you can't force it

What .NET or .NET Framework are you using, on what OS? In .NET Core, which includes .NET 5 and later, HttpWebRequest is just a legacy adapter over HttpClient and should only be used while migrating to HttpClient. And, as the docs warn ServicePointManager has no effect in .NET 9

ServicePoint.ProtocolVersion is the HTTP Version, not the SSL Protocol version. That's why you read 1.1. sender is not a SslStream

I want to specify a TLS version in order to prevent using TLS 1.1.
I use .net 4.8 but good information about the legacy implementation under Core
@Jimi, you are correct, this is the wrong way to check. Is there any other way than tracerts to see the tls version used (in IRestResponse)

Did you misnumber something in the server supports TLS 1.2, TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3? Did you mean to include 1.1 in there? The two parties negotiate the best possible transport first. If your application works on a server, you should never, ever, set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol (which is now deprecated). ServicePointManager was used in client desktop applications, in Windows 7, before the 4.7.2. update -- If you're interested: Which TLS version was negotiated?. But you shouldn't be that much interested as of now

@Jimi, yes misnumbered. Only 1.2 and 1.3 are supported on the serverside. And I have to make sure the client uses 1.3 all of the times. Later there can be different servers with the same implementation of servercode but different security configuration. Therefore I want to check which TLS version is used
